# How to get substring in a matched annotated expression UIMA RUTA?

Tags: uima, ruta

I am trying to implement substring of a matched annotation.

```
Eg:
Input : 1A2S3DWER
Expected Output: WER
Expected Output: 1A2S3D
```

Below is what I tried:

```
Document{->RETAINTYPE(SPACE)};
((W|NUM) (W|NUM)*){REGEXP("([A-Z0-9]{9})")->MARK(EntityType)};
```

I don't know how to separate the matched annotation.
Please guide me through.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What identifies a substring, e.g., why do you split on 'WER'?

Comment: @PeterKluegl: A policy number which is alphanumeric (1A123ABCAPLB).
The last 3 characters of a policy number is a product code.
So, I wanted to extract the last 3 characters.
But I am stuck on how to do it.
please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

In your example "DWER" is one CAP. You need to split it up into several annotations, e.g., with a simple regex rule:

```
DECLARE EntityType, ProductCode, Prefix;
ADDRETAINTYPE(WS);
(ANY+{-PARTOF(EntityType), PARTOF({NUM,W})}){REGEXP("([A-Z0-9]{9})")-> EntityType};
REMOVERETAINTYPE(WS);

EntityType->{"^(.*)(...)$"-> 1=Prefix, 2=ProductCode;};
```

DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta